# Custom Theme Attributes?

Tags: android, android-layout

So here's what I'm trying to do.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/label_block"
    android:layout_width="308dp"
    android:layout_height="154dp"
    android:layout_margin="?attr/primaryMargin" <!----- THIS HERE
```

I'd like to be able to reference my own attributes just like how you can reference android theme attributes like *android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"* 
The goal is to have a centralized place for all my paddings and other common values to reference them in xml layouts.

Is there anyway I can do this? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can define your Dimensions like this way:

in path **/res/values/dimensions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_layout_margin">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="my_other_value">4dp</dimen>    
</resources>
```

and you will reference it like this way:

```
<RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/label_block"
    android:layout_width="308dp"
    android:layout_height="154dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/my_layout_margin"/>
```

Comment: ok. that's fairly nice and should achieve what I need. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item"               
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_block"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/label_block" />
```